# Why can't I modify the contents of this folder when I'm part of the group with full permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, permissions, group-policy

```
dsmith@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx:~$ groups dsmith
dsmith sudo py
dsmith@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx:~$ sudo chmod -R g+rwxt /usr/local/virtualenvs
dsmith@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx:~$ ls -al /usr/local
...
drwxrwxr-x  2 root py   4096 2010-02-17 19:36 virtualenvs
dsmith@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx:~$ echo "Hello World" > /usr/local/virtualenvs/test.txt
bash: /usr/local/virtualenvs/test.txt: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have read (well, execute at least) on all parent directories, and write access to the file in question.

Also, `groups dsmith` shows what groups the *dsmith* user is in; while `groups` shows what groups the *current user* is in. You'll need to log in anew if they show different output.

Another thing to check is SELinux; it might be interfering.

Comment: groups returned dsmith sudo. I logged out and logged in as dsmith and it worked. A few steps back I su dsmith so I wonder if switching users instead of logging out and logging in as a different user had something to do with it.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that if you add the current user to a new group, that new group won't be recognized until you logout and log back in again - or su to the same user.